# смысл ключевого слова extern?

Tags: c++

Всем привет.Я не понимаю смысл ключевого слова extern.
У меня 2 файла компиляции 1.cpp и 2.cpp в 1 пишу объявления функции

```
int foo();
```

а во 2 определяю:

```
int foo(){
return 3;
}
```

И в чем смысл писать extern,когда если я пишу сигнатуру функции в 1 файле и в нем же его использую без каких либо ошибок? В чем вообще смысл extern и когда в основном это используется?

Comment: Никакого. А если функция используется только в том файле, где и реализуется, то имеет смыл объявить ее как `static`

Comment: а смысл тогда вообще extern?

Comment: extern может понадобиться, когда указывается линковка другого языка, например `extern "C"`

Comment: Более частое применение - достать переменную (не функцию) из другого файла.

Comment: Считай, функции по-умолчанию extern. :)

Comment: Слово `extern` нужно использовать при объявлении глобальных переменных в заголовочном файле. Без этого слова будет не объявление, а уже определение глобальной переменной. При включении же такого заголовочного файла в несколько компилируемых модулей на этапе линковки будет обнаружена ошибка многократного определения одного и того же символа в нескольких модулях. В прототипах функций (тоже в заголовочных файлах) писать `extern` не обязвательно. Другие случаи применения `extern "C"` относятся к манглированию имён функций для связи с модулями не на c++, или шаблонам `extern template`.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас в файле `1.cpp` есть функция которую вы хотите использовать в файле `2.cpp` без дублирования кода этой функции и выноса ее в заголовочный файл, тогда можете добавить необъязательный оператор `extern`, который и без того додается ко всем членам одного `translation unit`, которые не `static` и он будет скорее явно говорить о том, что данная функция из другого ТЮ.

Comment: а когда мы объявляем функцию,код дублируется?

Comment: @javayhaster ну с такой стороны то дублируется только сигнатура функции. Сама реализация между двумя файлами будет связана линкером.

Answer (score 0):

Функцию Вы можете объявлять без extern любое количество раз в разных единицах трансляции. А вот **переменную** можно объявить только один раз и если она понадобиться в другой единице трансляции - то без extern вам к ней доступа не получить:
1.cpp:

```
int i; // Объявление и сразу определение
```

2.cpp:

```
int i; // объявляем и сразу определяем новую переменную i в глобальной области видимости,  внешнее связывание. Имеем ошибку компиляции.
```

**или:**

```
extern int i; // при линковке объектных файлов, полученных из 1.cpp  и 2.cpp, получаем доступ к i из первого файла.
```

Comment: Придирка: переменную тоже можно сколько угодно раз *объявлять*. `extern int i;` - это объявление, а `int i;` - определение (и одновременно объявление).